# Splitting numbers into smaller groups

Tags: python-3.x

I believe this question is leaning more towards developing the logic than implementation.

I have a 6 digit int value which I need to split into three, three digit numbers.

This is a trivial task but I cannot use any indexing or slicing operations.

Input -

```
rgb1 = 220020060

rgb2 = 189252201
```

My expected output is of the form

```
r1 , g1, b1 = 220, 020, 060
r2,  g2, b2 = 189, 252, 201
```

I have tried using `divmod()` but unsure of how to get the middle set of values if it is of the form `0x0` where `x` is any single digit integer.

For example:

```
r, rest = divmod(rgb1,10**6)

r = 220, rest = 20060
```

But I am unsure as to how to proceed with extracting further numbers.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is convert the number to string if 0xx cases exists, as 'int' cannot display leading zeros.

**My code:**

```py
def splitter(num):
    r1, rest=divmod(num,10**6)

    if len(str(r1)) !=3:
        r1=str(r1)
        r1=r1.zfill(3) 

    if len(str(rest)) !=6:
        rest=str(rest)
        rest=rest.zfill(6)

    g1,rest=divmod(int(rest),10**3)

    if len(str(g1)) !=3:
        g1=str(g1)
        g1=g1.zfill(3)

    if len(str(rest)) !=3:
        rest=str(rest)
        rest=rest.zfill(3)

    b1=rest

    return r1,g1,b1
```

**Output:**

```py
>>> splitter(220020060)
(220, '020', '060')
```

You can edit the code to display the output in the format you need!

Comment: This is a nice way to do it, but I  have a doubt here. The code returns one int value and two str values, so if i want to do an operation on the 'str' values i won't be able to do that right?

Comment: @PyWalker27 I had to make some numbers str as int won't allow you to store a number starting with 0. However you can still perform any operation you want to. For example, let's consider g1 and b1 to be str, and r1 to be int. To find sum of r1,b1 and g1, you can do `r1+int(b1)+int(g1)` and get the sum to be `220+20+60=300`

Comment: Yes it works! I got myself confused a little bit there, but now it's sorted. Thank you!